# Torch: max value of each channel in an rgb image

Tags: image-processing, lua, torch

I am trying to get the max value of each channel in an rgb image. 
Currently, I am iterating over each channel separately like this:

```
r_max = rgb[1]:max()
g_max = rgb[2]:max()
b_max = rgb[3]:max()
```

Is there any way to comprehend this into a single statement in Torch? Could someone please help me with possible solutions?

Comment: not much nicer but you could move to to one line: r_max,g_max,b_max = rgb[1]:max(), rgb[2]:max(), rgb[3]:max()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Max takes an optional 'dimension' argument. 
Using this on the dimensions other than channel will give you a 3x1x1 tensor, which you can flatten if needed, e.g.

```
 rgb_max = rgb:max(2):max(3):reshape(3)
```